# A Java Mesh Library?

Tags: java, mesh

I'm currently looking for a Java Mesh Library.
If my understanding is correct, this would be something similar to OpenMesh.

All I've found at moment is JMesh 'A Polygonal Mesh Library in Java' ( http://jmesh.origo.ethz.ch/ ) which is still in development.

Context : turning a very large stl file into a Mesh structure (probably winged- or half-edged, but again I'm not too familiar with this field) in order to perform Mesh simplification operations (edge collapse, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The existing tools written in C++ (OpenMesh & OpenFlipper) are very well optimized.

Java alternatives are still in development.

While implementing a basic HalfEdge structure (and basic operations like Edge Collapse) in Java is not hard, handling the persistence of data is harder/slower.
I have a proof of concept of a HalfEdge structure built in J2EE with persistence via EJB3/Hibernate but alot of work wood be needed to develop all the features of OpenMesh.

Conclusion: use OpenMesh.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at:

JavaMonkeyEngine: http://www.jmonkeyengine.com

LWJGL: http://www.lwjgl.org

the Java3D API might also have useful information of directions to support for what you need.

Comment: Those are great to render graphics but what I really need is the ability to import and modify a Mesh.
Read from stl files.
Chose a data structure (winged-edge for example).
Use basic algorithms (edge collapse, etc.).

Those are things I could code, but if a library already exists it would save me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

There are two excellent libraries (for processing.org originally but not an hard constrains, they can be used genetically) :

Toxic libs for winged mesh, [toxiclibs.org](http://toxiclibs.org)

He mesh for half edge mesh, http://hemesh.wblut.com

Both can load sto and do various  simplification operations.